# SSIS Cross-DB "WHERE IN" Clause (or Equivalent) in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I'm currently trying to build a data flow in SSIS to select all records from a mapping table where an ID column exists in the related Item table. There are two complications:

1. The two tables are currently in different databases on different servers.
2. The databases are in Azure, for which I've read Linked Servers are not supported.

To be more clear, the job to migrate data from Staging environment to Production. I only want to push lookup records into prod if the associated Item IDs are in there. Here's some psudo-TSQL to give a clear goal of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Staging_Server].[SourceDB].[dbo].[Lookup] L
WHERE L.[ID] IN (
    SELECT P.[Item]
    FROM [Production_Server].[TargetDB].[dbo].[Item] P
)
```

I haven't found a good way to create this in SSIS. I think I've created a work-around that involves sorting both tables and performing a merge join, but sorting both sides is an unnecessary hit on performance. I'm looking for a more direct and intuitive design for this seemingly simple data flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this in a data flow, you'd have your Source query, sans filter, fed into a Lookup Component which is the subquery.

The challenge with this is SSIS is likely on-premises so that means you are going to pull all of your data out of Stage Azure to the server running SSIS and push it back to the Prod Azure instance.

That's a lot of network activity and as I'm reading the Azure pricing guide, I guess as long as you have the appropriate DTUs, you'd be fine. Back in the day, you were charged for Reads and not Writes so the idiom was to just push all your data to target server and then do the comparison there, much as ElendaDBA mentions. Only suggestion I'd make on the implementation is to avoid temporary tables or ad-hoc creation/destruction of them. Just implement as a physical table and truncate and reload prior to transmission to production.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution, thanks billinkc. I thought I would have needed a component that allowed 2 inputs (one for data and another for the filter keys), so I initially dismissed "Lookup", but it's actually perfect for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp table on staging server to copy production data into. Then you could create a query joining those two tables. After SSIS package runs, you could delete the temp table on staging server